# How to handle Python try/except with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, exception, instagram

I am trying to use Selenium to following people on Instagram.

But my big problem is on the loop when iterate all profile for distinguish public/private users (cause by different element on page).
On my code when the loop reach an private profile, the `except` start on first after `try` start after that.

My code :

```
followers = [ #url of all users]

for follower in followers:
    #Iterate into the list
    browser.get(follower)
    sleep(2)
  
  try:
     browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li:nth-of-type(2) a.-nal3 span").get_attribute("title"):
     print("Public profil") 
     #click on follow                  
  
  except NoSuchElementException:
     print("private profil")
     follower_count = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li:nth-of-type(2) span.-nal3 span").get_attribute("title")
     if follower_count == 0:
        pass
        print("0 followers")
      
     else:
        print("go follow")
```

I think understood properly, if `except` corresponding clause is executed, then execution continues after the statement `try` but that doesn't explain why the loop ended after `except`.

error :
[image]

Comment: Maybe typo? `a.-nal3` and  just `-nal3`

Comment: @vitaliis not a same, public user : `a.-nal3 span` ; for private user : `-nal3 span`

Answer (score 0):

In your NoSuchElementException, you are again writing

```
     follower_count = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li:nth-of-type(2) span.-nal3 span").get_attribute("title")
```

I expect this is raising another NoSuchElementException since you're trying again to find the same element.

Comment: it's not exactly the same.  One is `span.-nal3 span`, the other is `a.-nal3 span`.  I thought the same thing myself at first.